# Network order query using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I have written a powershell script to query NIC binding order and the script will look NIC binding order in the format Vethernet,storage if this order is correct then it will print output in green color else it will print in yellow color.
Also I have added one more condition here, i.e if there is no storage NIC found in the binding order it should see Vethernet is the first in order and if the order correct,it should print as green or else it should be yellow.But there seems to be some problem with my script.

The first if condition line work perfect, but the second else if condition doesn't work well. I have tried changing the order , even after changing order it print the color as green.

Can anyone help me correcting this script ?

```
$results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage").Bind | ForEach-Object {
  $guid = ($_ -split '\\')[2]
  Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE GUID='$guid'" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetConnectionID
}}

$adapteresult = $results -join","

if (($adapteresult.Contains('Storage') -and ($adapteresult -match 'vEthernet\s+\([^)]+\),storage')))
{
Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Aquamarine'  height='25' align=center><B>$adapteresult</B></td>"
}
elseif ($adapteresult -NotContains "Storage" -and ($adapteresult -match 'vEthernet\s+\([^)]+\),'))
{
Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Aquamarine'  height='25' align=center><B>$adapteresult</B></td>"
}
else
{
Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Yellow'  height='25' align=center><B>$adapteresult</B></td>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, you can check the with *$Null*

Just add the Condition with OR like :

```
if (($adapteresult -match 'vEthernet\s+\([^)]+\),storage') -or ($adapteresult -eq $null))
```

As per the update, Why to use multiple if else:

```
if( ($adapteresult -match 'vEthernet\s+\([^)]+\),storage') -or ($adapteresult -match 'vEthernet*\s+\([^)]+\),') )
{
Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Aquamarine'  height='25' align=center><B>$adapteresult</B></td>"
}
else
{
Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Yellow'  height='25' align=center><B>$adapteresult</B></td>"
}
```

Comment: Actually I am looking for something different here. First condition should be to search the if the binding order in this format vethernet, storage and this is working in my above script and what I want here is , the script should also search if the storage NIC found in binding order or not, if not found in the order,the script should see vethernet is first in order .if vethernet is first in order then it should pass

Comment: I have updated my script above. Can someone correct me now ?

Comment: @Sandeep: getting any error? What is output you are getting ?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Even now when I change the binding order , I could still see the color as yellow. IS that Vethernet * causing the problem ?

Comment: I think your match is not working. Instead of regex match, could you please try like operator

Comment: Like doesnt work either. I have again updated my script

Comment: Show me the names of the network adapters what you are having. and the corresponding headers. May be you can put it in github or pastebin and share the link.

Comment: This is from one server . vEthernet (Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X540-AT2 #2 - Virtual Switch),Ethernet 4,Ethernet 3,Ethernet. In some servers, vethernet((10.10.102.0_21) etc

Comment: so you can check with simple vEthernet* and not the regex. First you pick the match and see if its working, then the condition will come

Comment: updated the script above, still it doesn't work for me